# Oracle Apex download csv for a no data in interactive report

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle-apex

I am producing an interactive report.  When there is no data on the web page:
[image: No data]

if a downloading  a csv File  on  an  interactive report (Which has no data)  through Actions->  download
[image: Download from menu]
it creates a CSV file which includes `ORA-22275 : Invalid LOB Locator Specified` in the file.

CSV file contents:

[image: CSV Contents]

Comment: Voting to close : "Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement* are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" . Good luck.

Comment: Attachments added

Comment: I've just tested it on apex.oracle.com; works as expected, i.e. returns an empty CSV file when there's *no data found*. It is Apex 5.1.4. Which version do you use? Perhaps it is time to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

If your interactive report SQL query includes a table column that is a datatype CLOB or BLOB or LONG, that is probably causing the issue.  You could exclude that column from your interactive report SQL if possible, or if the column is a CLOB, you could do a

```
substr(really_long_description, 1, 4000) as really_long_desc
```

on it.